# tsnode with new AsyncFunction gives error

Tags: node.js, promise, ts-node

```
const AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function () {}).constructor

const fn = new AsyncFunction('a','await blah')
```

So I'm trying to create a function using [new AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction)

This is working perfectly on the server. But when I do `tsnode script.ts`, I got

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

for the exact line.

Somehow tsnode is creating a normal function instead of an async one. Is there any trick around this?

Comment: Hey, I am running into the same issue, have you ever found a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the exact fn defintion in string is:

```
`try{ ${js}\n return await ${fnName}(${args}) \n}catch(err){console.log('err ',err)}`
```

So if I get rid of `await`, it works ie

```
`try{ ${js}\n return ${fnName}(${args}) \n}catch(err){console.log('err ',err)}`
```

Still doesn't resolve the main tsnode async-fn creation problem, but this is a trick that unstucks me

Comment: If that's the body of the async function, it's buggy - if you don't await it within the try/catch block, you might as well remove that block because any error won't be caught in there, since it's not being awaited.

Comment: @404 good points; that makes the try/catch block becomes useless indeed